# Deserializing of untrusted data using C#

Tags: static-code-analysis, checkmarx

I have the following C# code which is getting a "high" error from Checkmarx. I can't see anything wrong with it.

```cs
var dataDirectoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString(); 
var json = File.ReadAllText($"{dataDirectoryPath}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}somefile.json");

var settings = new
    JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.None};     
var targetPathSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TargetPathSetting>>(json, settings);
```

It gives this error:

> The serialized object ReadAllText processed in xxx in the file yyy is deserialized by DeserializeObject in the file zzz

The C# code is as follows:

```cs
public class TargetPathSetting
{
    public string PathSettingName { get; set; }
    public PathSetting PathSetting { get; set; }
}


public class PathSetting
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationIdUri { get; set; }
}
```

I can't see that anything that is ever in the file is going to cause any sort of problem, especially with the TypeNameHandling.None setting.

Comment: I don't get this result for your code.

Comment: It's a fragment of a larger bit of code but the json file is a variable in the actual code. Does that matter?

Comment: I don't know. Do you know what is the name of the error? Is this `Deserialization_of_Untrusted_Data`?

Comment: Yes it is Deserialization_of_Untrusted_Data

Comment: I have edited the question to add the actual code to get the filename

Comment: this I believe is a false positive since you already have TypeHandling set to none as a security measure

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the standard Checkmarx query for c #. In this case, Checkmarx does not recognize the correction of this code. To fix it you should use CxAudit and modify this query.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to explain how to modify the query and possibly also explaiin how to use CxAudit.

Comment: CXAudit is an product add-ons of Checkmarx. Check Checkmarx WIKI for use and more. But this is a tricky things to do, if you don't know how to